# OLAP And Stored Procedures, Performance Differences and Facts

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm currently reading a book, *Delivering Business Intelligence with Microsoft SQL Server 2012, Third Edition*. In this book, it has a section that states the following:

> **Features of a Data Mart**
>
> Because the data mart is meant to serve as a source for business intelligence rather than managing the organization’s day-to-day transactions, it is not designed the same as an OLTP database. Instead of being built around the rules of normalization, data marts are built for speed of access. A data mart is still a relational database, but it is designed to require fewer table joins when data is output for analysis and reporting. In a data mart, it is acceptable to have data repeated (denormalized) for the sake of speed.
>
> When designing a data mart, the rules of normalization are replaced by a different method of design organized around “facts.” These new design approaches are called stars and snowflakes. We discuss stars and snowflakes in the sections “The Star Schema” and “The Snowflake Schema.” Stars and snowflakes may seem like the stuff of children’s fantasies, but, in reality, they provide quite grownup and down-to-earth approaches to creating information that is quick and easy to access.

What a great piece of information! But this is where confusion started to set in. I know that SQL Server allows the use of Stored Procedures as a way to optimize query performance. Although I don't know the inner workings of these, I know that the server has a built in way of optimizing query performance to quickly run queries in a traditional, normalized database. For instance, suppose I have a Sales table that has a listing of 20,000 lines that are all individual products that have been sold. If I want to know the sum total of these lines, I'd probably save the query `SELECT SUM(SALES.SALESPRICE) FROM SALES` in a Stored Procedure.

If I know that stored procedures are pre-compiled, then wouldn't the server automatically know that it has to get this sum and cache the result of the query each time an insertion is done? So, Whenever line 20,001 is added, the amount of the sale would automatically be saved so the result of the above stored procedure is instantly available? Isn't that the entire idea behind an execution plan? Or have I missed entirely what an 'optimized' query does?

If this is not the case, I'd appreciate understanding the inner workings of a Stored Procedure and how it yields a performance benefit over doing a straight query from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have rather missed the point, I'm afraid.

One benefit of a stored procedure is that calculating *how* to get the results as opposed to *what* the results are also takes processing time - and it is this `execution plan` that is cached by the stored procedure.

See http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

Perhaps a greater benefit of stored procedures is in the ability to more granularly secure access to your data, and to hide or change your schema without changing the external (SP) interface - ie: I can prevent any users from issuing `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` commands against my data, merely allowing them access to certain procedures which perform similar tasks, or multiple tasks.

If you did want to store the results of your sum calculation, you could do that, but it would have to be either in a dedicated table, or in an additional field in an existing table if the sum was to be grouped - and the calculation would have to be written manually - either in a trigger on the `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` events, or by additional code in the stored procedures that you write to do these data manipulation functions - so now your stored procedure reads something like

```
create proc SellProduct (@productID int, @price money)
as
begin
    insert ProductSales (ProductID, SalePrice) values (@productID, @price)
    update Products set TotalSales = TotalSales + @price WHERE productid = @productID
end
```

(and you'd probably want to read about transactions before finalising the above code)

Answer (score 1):

so, I removed the MDX tag because your question is regarding stored procedures, you are just using olap to exemplify your question.

So, when you say that stored procedures are pre-compiled, bear in mind that this does not apply to the result of the procedure. If you have a procedure with the select (sum), everytime you run it, the select (sum) will be submited to the database. The result is not stored anywhere.

You mentioned performance benefit. You wont have any performance benefit from wrapping a query inside a procedure. Behind the scenes, the query will be executed exactly no matter if it is inside a proc or not. Benefits of procedures are more related to waht @podiluska said.

I think your main confusion (based on this line your worote: `Whenever line 20,001 is added, the amount of the sale would automatically be saved so the result of the above stored procedure`)  is that you think a proceure is an object that contais data, and it is not. Procedures, views (non-persistent) and functions are mechanisms you use to better query or data

Answer (score 1):

OLAP stores results of a million different SUMs within your data mart. OLTP ('normal' SQL database) stores only the underlying data, and calculates a SUM when you call a stored procedure.

A stored procedure is compiled, like a C program. A SQL query you write outside of a procedure is translated at run-time, like an ASP webpage. Neither contain the data.